# Internet on wireless doesn't work without charger

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet, battery

My laptop is running on Ubuntu 12.04. Since last few days, I am facing a strange problem (some may even call me crazy after reading this). My laptop is Acer Aspire 5755 ([specifications](http://tech2.in.com/reviews/notebooks/acer-aspire-5755-notebook-review/241162/specifications) - just in case)

Wi-fi on my laptop is always on both in office and at home. At home, there are no issues with internet connectivity. However in office, internet works only when my charger is plugged in. I have tested in dozens of times to ensure it wasn't a one off thing.

At home, internet works fine with or without charger plugged in so it doesn't seem like it's an issue with the wireless card not getting enough power. It could have been an issue with the specific power switch on my desk but I tried it with several other switches in office and the problem persists.

Any help would be appreciated.

[**Update**] Added o/p of powertop command with device tabs selected. This is from office, will upload the o/p from home as well later today once I get back home.

PowerTOP 1.97     Overview   Idle stats   Frequency stats   Device stats   Tunables

```
          Usage     Device name
         12.6%        CPU use
        100.0%        Audio codec hwC0D0: Realtek
        100.0%        Display backlight
        100.0%        Display backlight
        495.2 pkts/s  Network interface: eth3 (wl)
        100.0%        Radio device: wl
        100.0%        USB device: Samsung Android USB Device (SAMSUNG Electronics Co., Ltd.)
        100.0%        Radio device: acer-wmi
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
        100.0%        USB Device: usb-device-8087-0024
        100.0%        PCI Device: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
        100.0%        USB device: EHCI Host Controller
        100.0%        PCI Device: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Memory Card Reader
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
        100.0%        PCI Device: Broadcom Corporation BCM43227 802.11b/g/n
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
        100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2
        100.0%        PCI Device: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller
          0.0%        USB device: EHCI Host Controller
          0.0%        USB device: xHCI Host Controller
          0.0%        USB device: xHCI Host Controller
          0.0%        USB Device: usb-device-8087-0024
          0.0%        USB device: 1.3M HD WebCam (BRB6G1NM1)
          0.0%        Audio codec hwC0D3: Intel
          0.0%        Radio device: acer-wmi
          0.0 pkts/s  Network interface: eth1 (tg3)
```

Comment: what are the types of wifi (n? g?) at home and at work? Did you notice anything relevant in `dmesg | tail` ?

Comment: At office, router is 'n' and at home, it's 'g'.

Comment: Please run `sudo powertop` (install if necessary) and screenshot the tab 'Device stats' at home and at work (with power connected).

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to upload the screenshots as it require at least 10 reputation to be able to upload images :( I'll try copy pasting the o/p.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I have the same problem with my laptop which is a Toshiba and I have a friend with the exact same laptop but he doesnt have the problem. It's strange though it works perfectly at home and many other public wifi connections but only at college I have this problem.

Comment: @Rory Not really but looks like the issue was related to a particular router. We changed it and everything started working fine. Probably the driver I had didn't support any of a/b/g/n standard which router was using.